# will Passing Android activity to a dependency ( a variable in the same class ) cause Memory Leaks

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-memory

I have code like this.

```
Class MyActivity {
private lateinit var downLoadQRHandler: DownloadQRHandler
...
fun someFun()

{     val model = getDataModelSomeOtherFun()
 downLoadQRHandler = DownloadQRHandler(downloadQRModel, this)
}
}
```

As the activity is passed to one of the dependencies?

Will it cause Memory Leaks?
At first I though, yes it would. BUt I think, after activity getting destroyed this reference downLoadQRHandler will automatically nullify. And MyActivity instance will be garbage collected.

to be on the safe side, I though of adding this in onDestroy()

```
  override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        downLoadQRHandler = null
}
```

Does it have any benefit of adding the ..= null code?

The activity class was flagged in the memoryProfiler and leakCanary. There could be other reasons for the memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Without see other piece of code it's not possible to answer you. If "downLoadQRHandler" is used elsewhere and retained in memory, yes it could be a memory leak especially if DownloadQRHandler() constructor (which accepts an Activity) holds the Activity for later use.

Comment: downLoadQRHandler is a variable of the activity. If the activity is destroyed won't its variable will be nullify.